# SCA and gradle wrapper integration

Tags: gradle, fortify, sourceanalyser

Noticed that I can use gradle with SCA on the documentation using

```
sourceanalyzer -b build gradle clean build
```

But I am trying to use a wrapper but I keep getting sourceanalyzer error=2...

```
>>>>>>>sourceanalyzer -b buildxyz ./gradlew clean build
starting init script
TaskListener registered.
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
> Task :clean


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script '/Users/.../.fortify/sca17.2/build/buildxyz/init-script4841163810233991317.gradle' line: 203

* What went wrong:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sourceanalyzer": error=2, No such file or directory
> Cannot run program "sourceanalyzer": error=2, No such file or directory

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.8.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Even by just using gradle, I get a different error...

```
>>>>>>>sourceanalyzer -b buildxyz gradle clean build
[warning]: File clean not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use three step process with Fortify & gradle:

1. Clean

   `sourceanalyzer -b ${SEC_REPORT_NAME} -verbose -clean`
2. Build

   ```
   sourceanalyzer -b ${SEC_REPORT_NAME} -gradle -verbose gradle -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/opt/jdk8 ${SEC_BUILD_TARGETS}
   ```
3. Scan

   ```
   sourceanalyzer -b ${SEC_REPORT_NAME} -verbose -scan -f ${SEC_TARGET}/${SEC_REPORT_NAME}.fpr
   ```

where `${SEC_REPORT_NAME}` is an application report id - should be the same for each step
`${SEC_BUILD_TARGETS}` are standard build targets for gradle ("clean build")
`${SEC_TARGET}` is output directory

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'sourceanalyzer' is not in the path because it cannot be found on the system based on this message:

- What went wrong:
  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sourceanalyzer": error=2, No such file or directory

  > Cannot run program "sourceanalyzer": error=2, No such file or directory

Ensure sourceanalyzer is installed locally and in the path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing this error, it's basically due to Fortify installation not added to the system's `PATH`.

You can technically do any of the following:

**MAC/Linux**

```
zsh:
export PATH="/Application/<Fortify Installation Dir>/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc

bash:
export PATH="/Application/<Fortify Installation Dir>/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
```

**Windows:**

Add the bin installation directory to the GUI path.